# PUT forbidden in SVN

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn

I have set up SVN 1.8.8 with Apache on RedHat running on AWS.

I am committing my first base code now and pushing all my current baselines into /tags.

Everything seems good, until I come to .rar files.  The commit is failing with the following error message.

I've tried to debug it for 2 days now.

- Ensured that my repositories are owned by 'apache' user
- There is no Deny directive in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf
- Added AddType for .rar
- Log shows that the PUT is via serf

Some may ask why am I committing a zipped file instead of the individual files.  Well, this particular .rar is an incoming deliverable and I would want to track it as an entire package, on top of the individual files that I am developing myself.

It is happening only to this file extension.  Can anyone help?

[image: Commit Failed]

Update 20140605:
I tried using CLI and force it to serf, same error.

[image: CLI]

Also, here is a snapshot of apache httpd's access_log.

```
192.101.84.225 - - [05/Jun/2014:05:34:13 +0000] "OPTIONS /svn/test/trunk HTTP/1.1" 401 517 "-" "SVN/1.8.9 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.5 TortoiseSVN-1.8.7.25475"
192.101.84.225 - tanst [05/Jun/2014:05:34:13 +0000] "OPTIONS /svn/test/trunk HTTP/1.1" 200 188 "-" "SVN/1.8.9 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.5 TortoiseSVN-1.8.7.25475"
192.101.84.225 - tanst [05/Jun/2014:05:34:13 +0000] "OPTIONS /svn/test/trunk HTTP/1.1" 200 97 "-" "SVN/1.8.9 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.5 TortoiseSVN-1.8.7.25475"
192.101.84.225 - tanst [05/Jun/2014:05:34:14 +0000] "POST /svn/test/!svn/me HTTP/1.1" 201 - "-" "SVN/1.8.9 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.5 TortoiseSVN-1.8.7.25475"
192.101.84.225 - tanst [05/Jun/2014:05:34:14 +0000] "HEAD /svn/test/trunk/testing.rar HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "SVN/1.8.9 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.5 TortoiseSVN-1.8.7.25475"
192.101.84.225 - tanst [05/Jun/2014:05:34:15 +0000] "DELETE /svn/test/!svn/txn/1-k HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "SVN/1.8.9 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.5 TortoiseSVN-1.8.7.25475"
```

There are no errors in error_log.

Comment: Did you talk to the administrator of the SVN repository? Perhaps they have a pre-commit hook set up to disallow committing certain file types.

Comment: Hi @Ben I checked and there are no hooks set up.  I don't think it's repository-specific.  I did a test by trying to commit the same filetype into another repository, I get the same error.

Comment: Try running `svn cleanup` against the working copy and see whether it helps.

Comment: Hi @bahrep I don't think that's the issue, because I tried it with some other .rar files in other repositories, same issue.  Anyway, did `svn cleanup` anyway out of desperation, no effect...

Comment: Update: I tried using CLI (svn commit --config-option=servers:global:http-library=
serf -m "rar file commit test"), same error